# How do I open a CSV file in IPython on Windows

Tags: python, csv, ipython

When I use Python for data analysis I  want to open a `csv` file in `IPython`. When I use this statement:

```
In [92]: open('ch06/ex1.csv').read()
Out[92]: 'something,a,b,c,d,message\none,1,2,3,4,NA\ntwo,5,6,,8,world\nthree,9,10,11,12,foo'
```

I directly open the file. How do I open the file as a table?

Comment: To form a table, you have to split the file in lines and, later, to split the lines in fields so that your table has rows, corresponding to lines, and columns, corresponding to fields. Because Python autosplits a file in lines when you iterate on a file object, what you want to do is very simple: `table = [line.split(',') for line in open('ch06/ex1.csv']` --- The expression in brackets is called a _list comprehension_ and is a useful construct, please google for "python list comprehension"... When you have a table you can print it or you can access the individual field, `table[row][column]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking but if you're into data analysis you should learn pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
myFile = pd.read_csv('ch06/ex1.csv')
myFile.head()
```

Comment: !cat /ch06/ex7.csv  What is converted to Windows statement